# Scrapy doesn't download all images of total pages

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrape

I've used Scrapy for crawling all images in 102 pages from this base url: https://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-di-dong/ . I set 60s delay before sending request to move to next page because this domain will block my crawling process when Scrapy send too much requests at the same time. In the process log, i see many notice lines of download in the first 2 pages:

```
...
...
2019-12-08 12:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.lazada.vn/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-12-08 12:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-di-dong/?page=1> (referer: None)
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 2 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/6d4a70571986291280d27d655f43c33b.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/ef903a6e40fac5cffde2fac25e9a695c.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/5292c25961bf9109d5896bc56f06f1eb.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/0e3f0321a5b12183d1caec077c5cddf7.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/d05e089b69960fa7e12851639db54833.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/c13858cf8aebf3a4474d07ca84100aca.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/ac8dfba90e44a4db294ab1ea95d6ec6f.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/e8a91ffdc7d36fd708bcc959b1e85a05.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/9b72137283d02a2c76ecc1a06f78ef5d.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/7d84fca1f4e4a423a6f7ecca1b462c65.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/95c8d5c76b9edc0c13168ee52ddb55d2.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/16021992d9b9ffb1d31bd4ed967cfda5.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/97d51ca35fe5953903b2c53913dc6204.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/69a75548dcb1e779a2c9b183a467c9b1.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/5580ad66d41ce6eaa91be9113d8e49d1.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/781c435a4e5d54ac0f0bd196cab6329b.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/90af16a3a5318aa38ac470ac0e78b4e1.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/7afcecd58b2ba746ce0bc360e78304fb.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/b6a6b9d9c1dca7eb4e79071ab5e04dfb.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/fd82fee9d2ec165e1c2bd5946d745660.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/ffdd4cdc5b1580c0426c341f0e54c04a.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/65a9ab76d5192a49a90222a7fdbad59f.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/1ebb07247431af734a0f956d9124a2a1.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/098a6071eeddc4d526ff310c8f4edbe3.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/40756a8648be2dbb416890f4f74fda3e.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/8b4b463d6c90b902858606b5978a96ff.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/80dee15ec45cfad725976c5947bf237d.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/5326c3132c9c11559fc75fe9ae9e2b63.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/cebe568afdcbad9f3719d1751a9b1117.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/ce771129fe8859a4609e796d51dc56aa.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/b51e6fcf692e5316cacde25913b86e89.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/6231fb489a949f6a7bf882ad8e85965b.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/3d80fa52c934a3999c8837402f852419.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/7016e51afc586d8725fec94f481f89a6.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/2e60c3233a708fa49c06964ed88792ba.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/2a347b03642f5e53c90fa03cfe8af63e.jpg> referred in <None>
2019-12-08 12:33:21 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/14adae58e3f65f087b6034eb165a1f20.jpg> referred in <None>
...
...
```

But from 3rd page to the end, i never see those anymore:

```
...
...
2019-12-08 12:34:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-di-dong/?page=3> (referer: None)
2019-12-08 12:35:22 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 13 pages (at 6 pages/min), scraped 80 items (at 40 items/min)
2019-12-08 12:35:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-di-dong/?page=3>
{'image_urls': ['https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/d05e089b69960fa7e12851639db54833.jpg'],
 'images': [{'checksum': 'dca1d5a23d29d3d1a854d35ff578e3f4',
             'path': 'full/e3bea7d5eb5bc56158e4e69f0312877c96e5ac6f.jpg',
             'url': 'https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/d05e089b69960fa7e12851639db54833.jpg'}],
 'price': '1290000.00',
 'title': 'Điện thoại oppo a37 neo9 fullbox ram2 bộ nhớ 16gb'}
2019-12-08 12:35:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-di-dong/?page=3>
{'image_urls': ['https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/e8a91ffdc7d36fd708bcc959b1e85a05.jpg'],
 'images': [{'checksum': '97f7bf79aed3e1013510e30673a35ee8',
             'path': 'full/e0b37ed8016f08a3aeb08cbf22c4096a1bf37fca.jpg',
             'url': 'https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/e8a91ffdc7d36fd708bcc959b1e85a05.jpg'}],
 'price': '2890000.00',
 'title': 'Điện thoại oppo f9 fullbox ram4 bộ nhớ 64gb Liên quân pubg chiến '
          'mượt'}
2019-12-08 12:35:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-di-dong/?page=3>
{'image_urls': ['https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/9b72137283d02a2c76ecc1a06f78ef5d.jpg'],
 'images': [{'checksum': '9b3990378a8b5152969369fcba144271',
             'path': 'full/e2d7a2a6a18b6791a8ed1d7fe8d9d35713f07d76.jpg',
             'url': 'https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/9b72137283d02a2c76ecc1a06f78ef5d.jpg'}],
 'price': '3390000.00',
 'title': 'Điện thoại IPH0NE_8_PLUS Hàng fullbox 256GB, tặng Tai nghe '
          'Bluetooth, Xả khó giá cực sốc'}
2019-12-08 12:35:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-di-dong/?page=3>
{'image_urls': ['https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/0951417571ed48aafd9e0b0108a42cb4.jpg'],
 'images': [{'checksum': 'f88bd5e92730b682b5d1925bbae3be4d',
             'path': 'full/4737babbe6e3238252c00a882e8bf9ab6529658e.jpg',
             'url': 'https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/0951417571ed48aafd9e0b0108a42cb4.jpg'}],
 'price': '1850000.00',
 'title': 'ĐIện_Thoại_IPHONE7_PLUS_256GB'}
2019-12-08 12:35:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-di-dong/?page=3>
{'image_urls': ['https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/55a39333530c4045e10b4589be0ad36a.jpg'],
 'images': [{'checksum': '0423081571336a25c01c8aa0d99c0458',
             'path': 'full/532b38fb6a4c95a55b0892e8fe76bae8ff031d26.jpg',
             'url': 'https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/55a39333530c4045e10b4589be0ad36a.jpg'}],
 'price': '2749900.00',
 'title': 'ĐIện_Thoại_IPHONEXS_MAX_512GB'}
2019-12-08 12:35:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-di-dong/?page=3>
{'image_urls': ['https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/a1162694a5b65056d8b2fff54d2fd7b7.jpg'],
 'images': [{'checksum': '78d8042b5b80d3f713846fab71ac583d',
             'path': 'full/0a8bd03ec3f5cb2c96439c99c503a9e40aa8afb3.jpg',
             'url': 'https://vn-test-11.slatic.net/p/a1162694a5b65056d8b2fff54d2fd7b7.jpg'}],
 'price': '1950000.00',
 'title': 'ĐIện_Thoại_IPHONE8_PLUS_256GB'}
...
...
```

At the end of the process, the result log show that Scrapy scraped 102 pages with about 4000 images but it downloaded only 153 images:

```
2019-12-08 11:34:21 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 259 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 4000 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-12-08 11:34:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-12-08 11:34:21 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 70175,
 'downloader/request_count': 259,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 259,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 27542657,
 'downloader/response_count': 259,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 259,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 6292.681676,
 'file_count': 153,
 'file_status_count/downloaded': 153,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 8, 11, 34, 21, 729083),
 'item_scraped_count': 4000,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4412,
 'log_count/INFO': 114,
 'memusage/max': 128307200,
 'memusage/startup': 55721984,
 'response_received_count': 259,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 4,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 4,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 102,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 102,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 102,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 102,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 8, 9, 49, 29, 47407)}
```

And here is my code:

**SIPDER**

```
import scrapy
import re
import json
from scrapy_lazada_test.items import ScrapyLazadaTestItem

class LazadaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lazada"
    allowed_domains = ['lazada.vn']

    def start_requests(self):
        max_page_number = 102
        base_url = 'https://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-di-dong/'
        for i in range(1, max_page_number + 1):
            url = base_url + '?page=' + str(i)
            #delay before sending request to move to next page
            time.sleep(60)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        result = response.xpath('//html/body/script[@type="application/ld+json"][2]').re(r'(?<=itemListElement":)(.*?)(\}\<\/script>)')
        products = json.loads(result[0])

        for p in products:
            item = ScrapyLazadaTestItem()
            item["image_urls"] = [p["image"]]
            item["title"] = p["name"]
            item["price"] = p["offers"]["price"]
            yield item
```

**ITEM**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class ScrapyLazadaTestItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
```

**SETTINGS**

```
BOT_NAME = 'scrapy_lazada_test'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['scrapy_lazada_test.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scrapy_lazada_test.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'scrapy_lazada_test (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

ITEM_PIPELINES = {"scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline": 1}
IMAGES_STORE = "/home/mmlab/scrapy_lazada_test/result/"

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 15
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16
...
...
```

I tried to set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1` but it still works the same way as before. How can i fix that?